# FPDF error: Unable to find "startxref" keyword

Tags: php, fpdf

I have an app that renders PDFs with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).

It was working fine and for some reasons I had to change the PDF files and now I get this error:

`Unable to find "startxref" keyword`

[image]

If I restore the original files, the same error happens.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply have to pass a local path instead of an URI to [setSourceFile()](http://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/#index-3-1).

Comment: I am getting a similiar error, however I am passing a local path. Could there be another reason for this error?

Comment: @user2085143 This error will also be raised, if the document is simply not a valid PDF document.

Comment: Also, If the pdf file is compressed it will rise this problem, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problems lies (**sometimes**) in the pdf compression.

If you are using linux you can use this to uncompress the pdf:

```
 podofouncompress compressed.pdf decompressed.pdf
```

Comment: That's wrong! The main error `Unable to find "startxref" keyword` could also occur from a corrupted PDF document. If the cli tool repairs the file it has nothing todo with pdf compression.

Comment: You are right , could also be the corruption of the PDF file or the compression. I will change it

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem recently. I'm using TCPDF to merge uploaded pdf files.
Curiousilly something went wrong when importing some pdf files. Some cases, following error was printed:

> Unable to find "startxref" keyword. in pdf_parser->_findXref()

So I tried to solve by reopen these pdfs files in Google Chrome and save it as PDF again. For my surprise, TCPDF worked! I still dont know how it can be but now I got a temporary solution.